# PHP 8.0 Syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Tags: php, phpmailer

RESUELTO

Estoy utilizando PHPMailer para enviar correos automáticos.

En la documentación de PHPMailer se especifica que para utilizarlo debo agregar el siguiente código:

```
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Este código se encuentra dentro de una función. El problema viene con que me arroja el siguiente error.

En NetBeans IDE el error es el siguiente:

```
Syntax error
 unexpected:    identifier 'PHPMailer'
 after:         use
 expected:      String,(
```

En Visual Studio Code el error es el siguiente:

```
Syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

El error que arroja al ejecutarlo es el siguiente:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a averiguar por qué me salta este error?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/523140/edit) para agregar el código donde aparece el error. Lo más probable es que tengas esos `USE` dentro de un bloque (condición, función, etc.) y deberías leer las [reglas de ámbito para importación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope) para saber dónde colocar esas líneas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error viene dado por que los "use" están dentro de una función, se solucionó al sacarlos de la función.